# Ошибка cannot convert float infinity to integer в момент кластеризации KMeans

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Подскажите, как можно её решить?

```
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters = int(np.round(np.divide(len(keywords), 5))),
                init = 'k-means++',
                n_init = 10,
                max_iter = 300,
                tol = 0.0001,
                n_jobs = 4)
k_means.fit(X)
```

В результате отработки кода ошибка "OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer"

Comment: какое-то из значений это очень большое число.

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что в вашем наборе данных X присутствуют значения равные бесконечности. Обычно это результат деления на ноль.

Посчитать среднее для точек, у которых некоторые координаты не определены (NaN) или являются бесконечностью (inf) - невозможно.

Чтобы увидеть число элементов равных бесконечности:

```
np.isinf(X).sum()
```